# Read first 5 lines from file and then the rest

Tags: java, io, java-io

Disclaimer: This is homework, so I'm working under some restrictions.

I need to read the first 5 lines of a file and use these strings to change labels and buttons, and then the rest of the file is saved as an arraylist.

The file looks like this:

```
Name  
Label1  
Label2  
Button1  
Button2  
Button3  
word0,word0  
word1,word1  
etc
```

I already have the ability to read the wordpairs in (word0,word0 etc) with the following code (the first 5 lines are additions, so it might not work now):

```
public static ArrayList loadFile(String filename) {
    ArrayList<Wordpair> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        FileInputStream fis;
        fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
        //Scanner to read individual lines from a file
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(fis);
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            //Scanner to read individual items from a string 
            Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);
            lineScan.useDelimiter(",");
            String question = lineScan.next();
            String answer = lineScan.next();
            //Create the new Wordpair
            Wordpair wp = new Wordpair(question, answer);
            //Add the new wordpair to the list
            temp.add(wp);
        }
        scan.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(IO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return temp;
}
```

My idea is to save the first 5 lines of the file as a separate object which only contains the information found in the file, but I have no idea how to do so. 
My initial thought was to create a new method which only read in the first 5 lines and then returned an object like the code above does with wordpairs, but I haven't been able to get anything working. And then I guess I'd need to make the existing code skip the beginning.

As you can see I'm pretty confused here, so if anyone could point me in the right direction I would be very grateful!

Comment: You could hardcode it - just assign 5 variables to the output of calling `scanner.next` 5 times. As the format is a little hardcoded this is probably the easiest approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a counter in your while loop.

```
int count = 0;
while (scan.hasNext()) {
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        //Scanner to read individual items from a string 
        Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);
        lineScan.useDelimiter(",");
        String question = lineScan.next();
        String answer = lineScan.next();

        if (count < 5)
          //lineScan contains one of the first 5 lines
          //call a method to do something with these lines here
        else {
          //Create the new Wordpair
          Wordpair wp = new Wordpair(question, answer);
          //Add the new wordpair to the list
          temp.add(wp);
        }

        count++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use from a counter in you loop:

```
int c = 0;
while (scan.hasNext()) {
    if (c < 5){
        //do something
        //first 5 lines
    }
    else{
        //otherwise
        //next lines
    }
}
```